# List to list assignment becomes garbage

Tags: c, list, pointers, parameters

I'm having some trouble with the following:

```
void BuildList(cs460hwp hw)
{

    FILE* fp;
    fp = fopen("HW2input.dat", "r");
    if(fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Couldn't open the file.");
        return;
    }
    int numStudents;
    int i;
    bool success;
    char* dueDate = malloc(9*sizeof(char));
    char* course = malloc(7*sizeof(char));
    char* wsuid = malloc(9*sizeof(char));
    char* subDate = malloc(9*sizeof(char));
    double points1 = 0;
    double points2 = 0;
    cs460hwp stuInsert = NULL;
    fscanf(fp, "%d", &numStudents);
    fscanf(fp, "%s", dueDate);
    for(i = 0; i < numStudents; i++)
    {
        stuInsert = malloc(sizeof(cs460hwp));
        fscanf(fp, "%s %s %s %lf", course, wsuid, subDate, &points1);
        strcpy(stuInsert->course, course);
        strcpy(stuInsert->wsuid, wsuid);
        strcpy(stuInsert->subdate, subDate);
        stuInsert->points1 = points1;
        stuInsert->points2 = CalculatePoints(dueDate, subDate, points1);
        stuInsert->nextPtr = NULL;
        if(hw == NULL)
        {
            hw = stuInsert;
        } 
        else
        {
            stuInsert->nextPtr = hw;
            hw = stuInsert;
        }
    }
    free(course);
    free(wsuid);
    free(subDate);
    free(dueDate);
    PrintGrades(hw);
    fclose(fp);
}

struct hwpoints
{
    char course[7];
    char wsuid[9];
    char subdate[9];
    double points1;
    double points2;
    struct hwpoints *nextPtr;
};

typedef struct hwpoints *cs460hwp;
```

My goal here is to insert every entry to the top of the list. However, whenever I try to assign anything to nextPtr (such as in the else clause), it gets filled with garbage values. They're mostly truncated versions of old data, which leads me to believe they're being taken from the heap. I've been reading (a lot), but I'm having trouble finding advice on this particular problem.

nextPtr always becomes junk, and nextPtr->nextPtr causes a segfault. For every iteration of the loop. hw remains fine, but its pointer value never gets updated properly.

Even when I've attempted to move the memory allocation for the struct into a function, I've had the same (or similar) issues.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Absolutely, I didn't even think to add it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two problems.

1) As pb2q mentioned, you are passing a pointer to a struct and trying to assign what the arg points to. That's allowed by the compiler, but it doesn't do anything for you outside the function. It might be OK in your case if:

```
void main()
{
   cs460hwp hw = NULL;
   BuildList(hw);
   return;
}
```

Is the whole of your function. I don't know the assignment so you need to figure out if that's acceptable to you or not.

2) The much bigger problem:

```
stuInsert = malloc(sizeof(cs460hwp));
```

Did you check what sizeof(cs460hwp) comes out to be? it's 4. You're allocating enough memory for the size of a pointer, not the size of your structure. I'm pretty sure this is not what you want to do and this is what is killing you. Just for kicks, replace it with malloc(100) and see if your problem goes away. If so you just need to figure out what size you really want. ;)

Comment: Ha! You got it with the second one. I knew it wasn't allocating enough memory, but was too dumb to jump the gap. Thank you very much. The rest works, now.

Answer (score 0):

A problem with your `BuildList` function is that you're passing a pointer to a `struct hwpoints`, and you're trying to re-assign what the argument points to. Since function arguments in C are *pass-by-value* you're only changing the *copy* of the pointer that your function receives, and those changes won't be reflected in the caller.

You *can* use this pointer to modify the contents of the list: you can change e.g. `hw->course` or `hw->nextPtr`, you can move elements around in your list. But you **can't** change what the head, `hw` points *to*, so you can't insert elements at the beginning of the list.

If you want to change your head pointer, as in these statements:

```
hw = stuInsert;
// ...
hw = stuInsert;
```

Then you'll need to pass a pointer to the pointer:

```
void BuildList(cs460hwp *hw)
```

And de-reference it as necessary in the body of the function.

I can't be sure that this is the cause of the output that you're observing, which may be due to other problems. But if, after some number of calls to `BuildList`, beginning with a head pointer equal to `NULL`, you're trying to print your list assuming that it has valid nodes, you could see garbage data.

Thanks to @Mike's answer, we see also that you're not allocating enough space for your list nodes:

```
stuInsert = malloc(sizeof(cs460hwp));
```

Will only allocate enough space for a *pointer*, since `cs460hwp` is `typedef`'d to be a pointer to `struct hwpoints`. You need to allocate enough space for the structure, not a pointer to it:

```
stuInsert = malloc(sizeof(struct hwpoints));
```

Comment: That's what I thought! My first idea was to use a double pointer, which I think would be much easier, but I have to use the function as defined. I should be able to work with the rest of the list via nextPtr, correct? For the moment, the head will simply be empty apart from the link. I'll try that now, thank you.

Comment: You _can_ work with the rest of the list as mentioned in the answer, yes. You _could_ regard the head as a dummy node and do list inserts only with the following nodes, but given your types it would be odd if you're assignment expected you to do this. Look over the assignment more carefully: could be that you've missed something important.